# cannot download certain packages?

Tags: centos, php, yum

I'm trying to install mcrypt, and I keep getting this error: 
[image: error]

i've tried `yum update` and rebooting the server, so does anybody have any solutions?

i run php-fpm on a centos 6 nginx web server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be trying to install the `php-mcrypt` package from EPEL but you have `php-common` installed from remi. They do not work together.

Ensure that you still have the remi repo installed and enabled if you want to use the remi packages or remove the remi versions and reinstall the epel versions of them all.